# LibGDX: SSL networking with WebSockets

Tags: android, ios, html, ssl, libgdx

I am currently working on a multiplayer game and I would like to use SSL encryption for all data transfer, since the game has a login system with passwords. The issue I am having is that I can't seem to figure out how to add the certificates for the different platforms that LibGDX supports. I would like to release it on all 5.

I figured out how to do it on Desktop. If was fairly easy to do. I just added these lines of code:

```
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "cacerts");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

The "cacerts" property value refers to a file I have in my assets folder called "cacerts". It has my certifications and all. "changeit" is the password. It works great. I just want to have it also work on **Android**, **iOS** and **html5**.

P.S. I also made the keystore.jks server.cer files.